# How to match array of candles in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

what is the best way to count the possibility of candles in array in Javascript;

example case:

Billy is collecting candles for his 25th birthday, he's got a box of candles, how much cakes possibly decorated?

```
const candles = [2,1,2,2,4,5,5,6,7]
// because 25 is a combination of candle 2 & 5, the possibility of candles can be used (25) should be 2 times.
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not clear what is the expected result.

Comment: Please be more concrete: 2 times is not a *probability*. I think the term probability makes no sense here. What information you want exactly? Maybe: How many cakes you could decorate given the available candles?

Comment: Also, please don't just post your homework without making any attempt yourself :)

Comment: @yezper yes, that is what exactly the point. sorry about the information given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it seems like you just posted your homework here without any effort, I am so bored that I implemented a solution for you using two helper functions and ES6 syntax. See [here](https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3yebdte65) for running the code in your browser.

```
const candles =  [2,1,2,2,4,5,5,6,7]
const age = 25

const possibleCakeDecorations = calculatePossibleCakeDecorations(age, candles)
console.log(possibleCakeDecorations)

// Calculates the possible cake decorations given the age that is to be
// displayed and the array of candles (each a single digit)
function calculatePossibleCakeDecorations(age, candles){
  // 2 -> 3, 1 -> 1, 4 -> 1, 5 -> 2, 6 -> 1, 7 -> 1
  const candleMap = countOccurences(candles)

  // getting each digit of the age separately
  var ageDigits = String(age).split("").map((num)=> {
    return Number(num)
  })
  
  // we identify the bottlenecking candle digit
  const bottleneck = Math.min(...ageDigits)

  return bottleneck
}

// Returns a hashmap with the occurences of the elements in the list
// Example: [2, 2, 1, 2] -> {2 -> 3, 1 -> 1}
function countOccurences(list) {
   
  const map = new Map();

  list.forEach((item) => {
    const key = item;
    const collection = map.get(key);
    if (!collection) {
      map.set(key, 1);
    } else {
      map.set(key, collection + 1);
    }
  });

  return map;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help!, sorry for the unclearance at the first.. this case just suddenly got in my head and want to solve it with most efficient way tho.

Comment: Please read ["How do I ask and answer homework questions?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/)

Comment: Note that this can be done with much less code, e.g., `const count = (t, xs) => xs .reduce ((s, x) => s + (x == t ? 1 : 0), 0);  const occurences = (age, candles) => Math .min (...String (age) .split ('') .map (d => count (Number(d), candles)))`